# Determine for which values ​of $\alpha$ the integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin x}{x^\alpha\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$ converges

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Determine for which values ​​of $\alpha$ the following integral converges:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin x}{x^\alpha\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx.$$

I attemped to do this: $-\frac1{x^\alpha\sqrt{1-x^2}}\le\frac{\sin x}{x^\alpha\sqrt{1-x^2}}\le\frac1{x^\alpha\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ but I'm stuck.

Comment: Hints: $\sin x\sim_0 x$ and $\sqrt{1-(1-h)^2}\sim_0\sqrt{2h}.$ Now, for which $\beta$'s is $x^\beta$ integrable at $0$?

Comment: Is it for $\beta \gt -1$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Comment: I think the result is $\alpha \lt 2$. Is it correct?

Comment: I found the same. I think you should [type your answer below](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: In the vicinity of $x \gtrsim 0$, the integrand behaves as $x^{1 - \alpha}$. Then, $\Re\left(\alpha\right) < 2$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Can you help me for this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4619533/how-to-find-the-character-of-this-series

Comment: Why don't you type an answer to the present post?